# How to print each row of an array with a loop for a graph to map a board

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, graph

I'm attempting to make a board that allows movement based on input similar to chess using c# and visual studio. I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it but I'm trying to use a 4x4 2d array to map out a grid with place values that can be modified. The focus of my question is how do I print a full grid out with a loop that follows the 4x4 graph build where not only row "a" and column "1" placeholders show array values. Also would it be wise to use a 2d array to map out a board with values on every space or would it be easier to manually make a board and assign values to each array withing the manually drawn board. This is a console project, I'm only looking for the basis of the code for now, and my overall goal is something similar to the board game risk. I should add I'm a bit new to programming and any advice on what i should use and shouldn't use throughout is helpful. I've marked off original code I planned on using where x and y would use loops to make "[]" to show a graph after realizing it wouldn't mark every placeholder of the 4x4 graph.

```
 class game
{
    int[,] board;
    string y;
    int x;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //for (int y = 0; y < 6; y++)
        {
         //   Console.Write("[]");
        }

        //for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++)
        {
          //  Console.WriteLine("[]");
        }


        int[,,] map = new int[,,]{
            {
            {0,0}, {1,0}, {2,0}, {3,0},
            {0,1}, {1,1}, {2,1}, {3,1}
            }
        };


        foreach (var item in map)
        {
            Console.Write("[" + item.ToString() + "]");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make this as effecient as possible while writing this.
So something like this:

```
    int[,,] map = new int[,,]{
        {
        {0,1,2,3},
        {0,1,2,3},
        {0,1,2,3},
        {0,1,2,3}
        }
    };


int width = map.GetLength(0);
int height = map.GetLength(1);
    for(int i=0;i < width;i++)
    {
       for(int j=0;j < height;j++)
       {

                Console.Write("[" + map[i,j] + "]");
       }
     Console.Write("\n");
    }
```

The \n signifies a new line in C#. Everytime you drop finish an array in a dimension it prints a new line.

I prefered to use for instead of foreach because it is faster for such cases. Foreach is for objects, For is for more mathematical issues.

Of couse you can change it as you see fit.

Comment: misha130 can I use that bit of code to modify the array values? Does the "map" call for the array and place each value using i and j to find maps size without excluding the array?  Readying for work and thanks.

Comment: Simply put yes. You can just change the console output to value assigment. The array limits were set on height and width so they wont go out of bounds.

Comment: Ironically, I need the \n to take affect after the first "4 array indexes" to get something like "[0,0] [1,0] \n [2,0][3,0]\n" ect. That's what I meant by 4x4 graph. Using \n in the current "Console.Write("[" + map[i,j] + "]");" loop will give me 2 [][] and then go to the next line. How can I make that possible if possible with a loop?

Comment: I added the map the declaration. In your original question you declared a 8x2 array not a 4x4. I am not sure how to explain this throughtly. The array data you put in the brackets are the values not the locations.